# regex : replace char '0' from a string

Tags: regex

I have a string like `'00122021300123024'`

I want to remove only single `'0'` not `'00'` means out put should be `'001222130012324'`

[NOTE : I am using ORACLE 11g regexp_replace function]

Comment: What about triple 0's? eg 000

Comment: Can you be more specific about what language you're doing this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without look around, search for `([123456789]|^)0([123456789]|$)` and replace by $1$2 where $1 is the first capturing group and $2 the second (or \1\2).

For Oracle SQL:

```
select regexp_replace('00122021300123024', '([123456789]|^)0([123456789]|$)', '\1\2') from dual;
```

Not tested but it should work.

Comment: not quite worthy of a separate answer, but a slightly more concise version is `([1-9]|^)0([1-9]|$)`

Comment: Yes indeed :) Forgot the dash

Answer (score 1):

If your language supports [look-aheads and -behinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can use:

```
(?<!0)0(?!0)
```

Comment: i am using ORACLE 11g regexp_replace.
could you please explain more.it is not working for me..

Comment: @vikash: I don't know what regex flavour they are using, nor how this function should be called, so no, I cannot give you any more information. It could very well be that they don't support lookaround, but that should be described in the documentation somewhere (as well as how to call that function). Moral: Always state form the beginning which language/regex flavour your are dealing with.

Comment: ORACLE 11g regexp_replace doesn't support look-around. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language your coding in, but heres how to do it in python:

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: x = "00122021300123024"
In [3]: print x
00122021300123024

In [4]: x_after_replace = re.sub("(?<!0)0(?!0)", "", x)

In [5]: print x_after_replace
001222130012324
```